# $A$ is diagonalizable $\implies$ $A^{2}=I$

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $A$ be a $n\times n$ matrix satisfying the equation $A^{m}=A$ for some $m>1$. Suppose that $N(A)=\{0\}$. Then prove that if $A$ is a diagonalizable then $A^{2}=I$.

**Attempts:** Since $A^{m}=A$ this says that for any $v \neq 0$ we have $A^{m}v = Av$ which gives us that $A \cdot (A^{m-1}v -v) =0$. Not sure what do from here on.

Comment: Please don't just regurgitate questions here without any further information or effort. What are your thoughts on the problem? What have you tried so far?

Comment: Maybe you should add $A^m=A$ to the title

Comment: If $A=\begin{pmatrix} \exp(2\pi i /3) & 0 \\ 0 & \exp(2\pi i /3) \end{pmatrix}$, then $A^3 = I$. Thus, $A^4=A$ and $A$ is diagonal, also $N(A)=\{0\}$, but $A^2 = \begin{pmatrix} \exp(4\pi i /3) & 0 \\ 0 & \exp(4\pi i /3) \end{pmatrix} \neq I$.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if you forget some hyphotesis like that the coefficient are reals, and $A$ is diagonalizable over the real field...with these assumptions the answer is the following.

Since $A \cdot (A^{m-1}v -v) =0$, then every vector $v$ is eigenvector with eigenvalue $1$. So $A^{m-1}$ is necessarily the identiy matrix. So $A$ is a diagonal matrix whose diagonal entries are real numbers such that $a_{ii}^{m-1}=1$. So the unique possibilities are $a_{ii}=\pm 1$. Then $A^2=I$.

Comment: The question did not specify that $A$ has real entries, or diagonalizable as real matrices.

Comment: You right! :) but as you state above without these assumptions the statement is false. So now I don't know what he mean.